# How do I use node_load() with an array as first parameter?

Tags: nodes, 8

In Drupal 6, I would use the following code.

```
$nodes = node_load(array('title' => $vcenter_name, 'type' => 'vcenter'));
```

What is the equivalent code for Drupal 8? I could use `node_load($nid)`, but not `node_load(array('title' => $vcenter_name, 'type' => 'vcenter'))`.

**UPDATE**

As per the answer , am getting the the `$nodes` array as

```
Array
(
    [1147] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object
        (
            [in_preview] => 
            [values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [vid] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 9272
                        )

                    [langcode] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => und
                        )

                    [revision_timestamp] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 1452106357
                        )

                    [revision_uid] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 0
                        )

                    [revision_log] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 
                        )

                    [nid] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 1147
                        )
```

and i can't access the fields like `$nodes->field_name[0]->value;`

But how i get like this :

```
Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object
(
    [in_preview] => 
    [values:protected] => Array
        (
            [vid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 9173
                )

            [langcode] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => und
                )

            [revision_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 1448312269
                )

            [revision_uid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 0
                )

            [revision_log] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 
                )

            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 1107
                )
```

Comment: better you can follow https://docs.acquia.com/articles/drupal-8-loading-entities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of `$values = array('title' => $vcenter_name, 'type' => 'vcenter'); $nodes = node_load($values);` for Drupal 8 is [`entity_load_multiple_by_properties()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load_multiple_by_properties/8.2.x), whose first parameter is the entity type, differently from `node_load()`.

Since `entity_load_multiple_by_properties($entity_type, array $values)` is deprecated, you should use the following code.

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties($values);
```

Comment: But its array key value is node id .  And i can't use it like **$nodes->field_name[0]->value;** How to resolve this ?

Comment: No, it's not the node ID: It's an array of properties. You can use any properties the node entity recognizes.